# How to reorder, add or delete home screens in the native Droid Maxx launcher?

Tags: launcher, motorola, motorola-droid

When booting up the Droid Maxx and not using a custom launcher, there are five swipe screens by defualt. Is there a way to reorder, add or delete screens? Usual two finger pinching or twirling has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Motorola devices are mostly loaded with a very basic Android build with minimum customization. The launcher which they provide is also very basic and light weighted and do have a lot of features. So if you are looking for customizing your home screens then you are not going to find any option in their default launcher.

You need to get a launcher from the Play Store. I will suggest the Google Now launcher. Its very basic yet has quite a few interesting features. I used it in my Moto G (1st Gen.) and it used to work pretty well. There are other good launchers too like Nova, Apex, etc. you can give them a try too.